# jsTree contextmenu issue

Tags: jquery, jstree

This should be a really simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.  I've recently (like today) began using jsTree and I just got my first tree set up.  I created an unordered list of just static text:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

My code to do a jsTree looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#demo1").bind("select_node.jstree",
                function(event, data) {
                    //DO SOMETHING WHEN A NODE IS CLICKED
                }).jstree();
});
```

Then I try to add a context menu.  Using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#demo1").bind("select_node.jstree",
                function(event, data) {
                    //DO SOMETHING WHEN A NODE IS CLICKED
                }).jstree({plugins: ["contextmenu"], contextmenu: {items: customMenu}});
    });
```

customMenu is a simple function that returns an object.

When I execute the first code, I get my jsTree and it collapses and expands.  When I execute the second one, the area where the jsTree is says "Loading..." and that is all. If I right-click that word, I DO get the menu.

Any suggestions?

if, when I point it to the function customMenu, I add the **()**, then I get a really strange menu that has:
-create
-rename
-delete
-edit
 --cut
 --copy
 --paste
--Add Group
--delete

I'm not sure I know what's going on.  I changed the function name to something different to be sure I wasn't getting a jQuery or jsTree function, but I still get the strange behavior. Any suggestions?

Comment: try here :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559543/configuring-jstree-right-click-contextmenu-for-different-node-types/11067303#11067303

Answer (score 2):

it would be suggested not to handle the contextmenu creation yourself, but rather let jstree do that for you.

so in the initialization code you would write:

```
$("#demo1").jstree(
{ 
    "plugins" : [ "contextmenu" ]
}
```

and that would be sufficient to have a functional contextmenu.

Answer (score 1):

dont bind the on select method to jstree. Instead create your new menu items as in the code below.
This should work fine.

```
$("#demo1").jstree(
{ 
     "contextmenu":{
         items:{
              "LogicalNameForMenuItem":{
                     label: "DisplayNameForMenuItem",
                     action: function (node) {
                          <--Your code to handle the function goes here-->
                     } 
               }
          }
      },

      "plugins" : [ "contextmenu","crrm","ui" ]

});
```

This should work.

And if you want to remove the default menu items then set them to false

```
"contextmenu":{
         items:{
            create:false,
            remove:false,
            ccp:false
         }
}
```