# JSTree Context menu Create Node is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I want to use context menu in jstree to create a node, but when I click on the Create in the context menu, nothing happens.... I get an error:

> this.create is not a function

JsTree's init is the following:

```
var $ = jQuery;
var baseUrl = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname].join('');
var ajaxUrl = baseUrl + "?action=load";

$("#tree").jstree({
    'core': {
        'data': {
            "url": ajaxUrl,
            "dataType": "json"
        }
    },

    "plugins": ["themes", "contextmenu", "search"],
    'contextmenu': {
        'items': function($node) {
            return {
                'Create': {
                    "separator_before": false,
                    "separator_after": false,
                    "label": "Create",
                    "action": function(obj) {
                        $node = this.create($node);
                    }
                },

                'Rename': {
                    "separator_before": false,
                    "separator_after": false,
                    "label": "Rename",
                    "action": function(obj) {
                        this.edit($node);
                    }

                },

                "Remove": {
                    "separator_before": false,
                    "separator_after": false,
                    "label": "Remove",
                    "action": function(obj) {
                        this.delete_node($node);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `this` refers to `window` entity, not `jstree`.

Approach, which worked for me:

```
createItem: { 
            label: "Create",
            action: function (data) {
                var inst = $.jstree.reference(data.reference),
                    obj = inst.get_node(data.reference);
                inst.create_node(obj, {}, "last", function (new_node) {
                    new_node.data = {file: true};
                    setTimeout(function () { inst.edit(new_node); },0);
                });
            }
        }
```

Also, you need to set `check_callback` like this:

```
'core': {
        'check_callback': true,
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930052/jstree-custom-contextmenu-not-filtering-based-on-type-folder-file)

[Full fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xpbf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you should get node of the tree with `var tree = $("#tree").jstree(true);`then operate on nodes.

u can use this [example](https://everyething.com/jsTree-with-Custom-Context-Menu).