# How to create a subset of uneditable leaf nodes with library(jsTreeR)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, jstree, jstreer

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a subset of uneditable leaf nodes with {[jsTreeR](https://github.com/stla/jsTreeR)}.

The expected behaviour for the leafs is, that they **can't** be:

- renamed
- deleted
- have own child nodes

Moreover, branch nodes should not be deleted if they have leafs.
However the leafs can be dragged and dropped among branch or parent nodes.

I've found the option `state = list(disabled = TRUE)` but this doesn't seem to affect the context menu:

```
library(jsTreeR)
library(shiny)

nodes <- list(
  list(
    text = "Branch 1",
    state = list(opened = TRUE, disabled = FALSE),
    type = "parent",
    children = list(
      list(text = "Leaf A", type = "child", state = list(disabled = TRUE), data = list(customdata = 1)),
      list(text = "Leaf B", type = "child", state = list(disabled = FALSE), data = list(customdata = 2)),
      list(text = "Leaf C", type = "child", state = list(disabled = FALSE), data = list(customdata = 3)),
      list(text = "Leaf D", type = "child", state = list(disabled = FALSE), data = list(customdata = 4))
    )
  ),
  list(text = "Branch 2", type = "parent", state = list(opened = TRUE))
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  jstreeOutput("jstree")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output[["jstree"]] <- renderJstree({
    suppressMessages(jstree(
      nodes,
      search = list(
        show_only_matches = TRUE,
        case_sensitive = FALSE,
        search_leaves_only = FALSE
      ),
      dragAndDrop = TRUE,
      multiple = TRUE,
      contextMenu = TRUE,
      types = list(default = list(icon = "fa fa-caret-right"), child = list(icon = "fa-solid fa-leaf"), parent = list(icon = "fa-brands fa-pagelines")),
      theme = "proton"
    ))
  })
}  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any hint is appreciated.

---

**Edit:** @StéphaneLaurent's approach wrapped in a shiny app:

```
library(jsTreeR)
library(shiny)

nodes <- list(
  list(
    text = "Branch 1",
    state = list(opened = TRUE, disabled = FALSE),
    type = "parent",
    children = list(
      list(text = "Leaf A", type = "undeletable", state = list(disabled = FALSE), data = list(customdata = 1)),
      list(text = "Leaf B", type = "undeletable", state = list(disabled = FALSE), data = list(customdata = 2)),
      list(text = "Leaf C", type = "undeletable", state = list(disabled = FALSE), data = list(customdata = 3)),
      list(text = "Leaf D", type = "undeletable", state = list(disabled = FALSE), data = list(customdata = 4))
    )
  ),
  list(text = "Branch 2", type = "parent", state = list(opened = TRUE))
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  jstreeOutput("mytree")
)

customMenu <- JS(
  "function customMenu(node) {",
  "  var tree = $('#mytree').jstree(true);", # 'mytree' is the Shiny id or the elementId
  "  var items = {",
  "    'delete' : {",
  "      'label'  : 'Delete',",
  "      'action' : function (obj) { if(node.type !== 'undeletable') tree.delete_node(node); },",
  "      'icon'   : 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash'",
  "     }",
  "  }",
  "  return items;",
  "}")

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output[["mytree"]] <- renderJstree({
    suppressMessages(jstree(
      nodes,
      search = list(
        show_only_matches = TRUE,
        case_sensitive = FALSE,
        search_leaves_only = FALSE
      ),
      dragAndDrop = TRUE,
      multiple = TRUE,
      contextMenu = list(items = customMenu),
      types = list(default = list(icon = "fa fa-caret-right"), undeletable = list(icon = "fa-solid fa-leaf"), parent = list(icon = "fa-brands fa-pagelines")),
      theme = "proton"
    ))
  })
}  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: A follow-up question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75732563/how-to-prevent-dropping-branch-nodes-on-leaf-nodes-with-libraryjstreer/75733349).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach (based on the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4600281/9841389)), which disables the context menu items instead of doing nothing after they were clicked.

The advantage is, that the items are greyed out.

The following also takes into account the problem of not allowing the deletion of branches having leaf nodes:

```
library(jsTreeR)
library(shiny)

nodes <- list(
  list(
    text = "Branch 1",
    state = list(opened = TRUE, disabled = FALSE),
    type = "parent",
    children = list(
      list(text = "Leaf A", type = "undeletable", state = list(disabled = FALSE), data = list(customdata = 1)),
      list(text = "Leaf B", type = "undeletable", state = list(disabled = FALSE), data = list(customdata = 2)),
      list(text = "Leaf C", type = "undeletable", state = list(disabled = FALSE), data = list(customdata = 3)),
      list(text = "Leaf D", type = "undeletable", state = list(disabled = FALSE), data = list(customdata = 4))
    )
  ),
  list(text = "Branch 2", type = "parent", state = list(opened = TRUE))
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  jstreeOutput("mytree")
)

customMenu <- JS(
  "function customMenu(node) {
  var tree = $('#mytree').jstree(true);
  var items = {
    'rename' : {
      'label' : 'Rename',
      'action' : function (obj) { tree.edit(node); },
      'icon': 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit'
    },
    'delete' : {
      'label' : 'Delete',
      'action' : function (obj) { tree.delete_node(node); },
      'icon' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash'
    },
    'create' : {
      'label' : 'Create',
      'action' : function (obj) { tree.create_node(node); },
      'icon': 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus'
    }
  }
  
  if (node.children.length > 0) { items.delete._disabled = true; }
  if (node.type === 'undeletable') { items.rename._disabled = true;
                                     items.delete._disabled = true;
                                     items.create._disabled = true;
                                    }

  return items;
}")

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output[["mytree"]] <- renderJstree({
    suppressMessages(jstree(
      nodes,
      search = list(
        show_only_matches = TRUE,
        case_sensitive = FALSE,
        search_leaves_only = FALSE
      ),
      dragAndDrop = TRUE,
      multiple = TRUE,
      contextMenu = list(items = customMenu),
      types = list(default = list(icon = "fa fa-caret-right"), undeletable = list(icon = "fa-solid fa-leaf"), parent = list(icon = "fa-brands fa-pagelines")),
      theme = "proton"
    ))
  })
}  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Cool! I'll add it to the examples in the package.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a custom context menu. Assign a type to the nodes you want to be undeletable and use it in the custom context menu:

```r
library(jsTreeR)

nodes <- list(
  list(
    text = "Menu",
    state = list(opened = TRUE),
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "this node cannot be deleted",
        type = "undeletable"
      ),
      list(
        text = "B"
      ),
      list(
        text = "C"
      )
    )
  ),
  list(
    text = "Drag here:",
    state = list(opened = TRUE)
  )
)

customMenu <- JS(
  "function customMenu(node) {",
  "  var tree = $('#mytree').jstree(true);", # 'mytree' is the Shiny id or the elementId
  "  var items = {",
  "    'delete' : {",
  "      'label'  : 'Delete',",
  "      'action' : function (obj) { if(node.type !== 'undeletable') tree.delete_node(node); },",
  "      'icon'   : 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash'",
  "     }",
  "  }",
  "  return items;",
  "}")

jstree(
  nodes,
  types = list(undeletable = list()),
  checkCallback = TRUE,
  contextMenu = list(items = customMenu),
  elementId = "mytree" # don't use elementId in Shiny! use the Shiny id
)
```

Here is a complete context menu, you have to modify it as above:

```r
customMenu <- JS("function customMenu(node)
{
  var tree = $('#mytree').jstree(true);
  var items = {
    'rename' : {
      'label' : 'Rename',
      'action' : function (obj) { tree.edit(node); },
      'icon': 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit'
    },
    'delete' : {
      'label' : 'Delete',
      'action' : function (obj) { tree.delete_node(node); },
      'icon' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash'
    },
    'create' : {
      'label' : 'Create',
      'action' : function (obj) { tree.create_node(node); },
      'icon': 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus'
    }
  }
  return items;
}")
```

Comment: For some reason it does not seem to work when I run it in a shiny app. Please see my edit.

Comment: @ahnungslos You have to add `undeletable = list()` to the `types` argument.