# How to prevent dropping branch nodes on leaf nodes with library(jsTreeR)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, jstree, jstreer

This is a follow-up post on my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75719149/how-to-create-a-subset-of-uneditable-leaf-nodes-with-libraryjstreer/).

@StéphaneLaurent and @ismirsehregal provided me with some great input on how to customize [jsTreeR](https://github.com/stla/jsTreeR)'s  context menu:

```
library(jsTreeR)
library(shiny)

nodes <- list(
  list(
    text = "Branch 1",
    state = list(opened = TRUE, disabled = FALSE),
    type = "parent",
    children = list(
      list(text = "Leaf A", type = "undeletable", state = list(disabled = FALSE), data = list(customdata = 1)),
      list(text = "Leaf B", type = "undeletable", state = list(disabled = FALSE), data = list(customdata = 2)),
      list(text = "Leaf C", type = "undeletable", state = list(disabled = FALSE), data = list(customdata = 3)),
      list(text = "Leaf D", type = "undeletable", state = list(disabled = FALSE), data = list(customdata = 4))
    )
  ),
  list(text = "Branch 2", type = "parent", state = list(opened = TRUE))
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  jstreeOutput("mytree")
)

customMenu <- JS(
  "function customMenu(node) {
  var tree = $('#mytree').jstree(true);
  var items = {
    'rename' : {
      'label' : 'Rename',
      'action' : function (obj) { tree.edit(node); },
      'icon': 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit'
    },
    'delete' : {
      'label' : 'Delete',
      'action' : function (obj) { tree.delete_node(node); },
      'icon' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash'
    },
    'create' : {
      'label' : 'Create',
      'action' : function (obj) { tree.create_node(node); },
      'icon': 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus'
    }
  }
  
  if (node.children.length > 0) { items.delete._disabled = true; }
  if (node.type === 'undeletable') { items.rename._disabled = true;
                                     items.delete._disabled = true;
                                     items.create._disabled = true;
                                    }

  return items;
}")

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output[["mytree"]] <- renderJstree({
    suppressMessages(jstree(
      nodes,
      search = list(
        show_only_matches = TRUE,
        case_sensitive = FALSE,
        search_leaves_only = FALSE
      ),
      dragAndDrop = TRUE,
      multiple = TRUE,
      contextMenu = list(items = customMenu),
      types = list(default = list(icon = "fa fa-caret-right"), undeletable = list(icon = "fa-solid fa-leaf"), parent = list(icon = "fa-brands fa-pagelines")),
      theme = "proton"
    ))
  })
}  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, on top of that I'd like to **prevent dropping *branch nodes* on *leaf nodes***.

Accordingly, instead of configuring it for the whole tree (`dragAndDrop = TRUE`) I'd like to distinguish between different node types:

**Allowed:**

[image: ok]

---

**Not allowed:**

[image: nok]

Comment: I think this is exactly the first example of `?jstree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need:

```r
dnd <- list(
  is_draggable = JS(
    "function(node) {",
    "  return node[0].type !== 'parent';",
    "}"
  )
)

jstree(
  nodes,
  dragAndDrop = TRUE, dnd = dnd,
  types = ......,
  checkCallback = TRUE
)
```

In this way, branch nodes are not draggable. Is it what you want?

---

## EDIT

Regarding your comment:

```r
checkCallback <- JS(
  "function(operation, node, parent, position, more) {",
  "  if(operation === 'move_node') {",
  "    if(parent.id === '#' || parent.type !== 'parent') {",
  "      return false;", # prevent moving a child above or below the root
  "    }",               # and moving inside a child
  "  }",
  "  return true;", # allow everything else
  "}"
)

jstree(
  nodes,
  dragAndDrop = TRUE, 
  types = ......,
  checkCallback = checkCallback
)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost it. Now I can't drag and drop branches at all. However, I'd still want to be able to nest branches via drag and drop (I just don't want to allow branches being childs of leafs).

Comment: `if(parent.type === 'child'){return false;}` works the way I want it. - Thanks!

Comment: @ahnungslos That's not possible: you have no `type = "child"` in your code.

Comment: and that's why I used `!== 'parent'` instead.

Comment: sorry I was using the package example you mentioned.

Comment: One more thing is strange here: After nesting the parents I can't get the lower parent back to the top level. Do you know why?

Comment: @ahnungslos This is because of `parent.id === '#'` I think.